# How do I review a Facebook app user's profile manually?

Tags: facebook, profile, image

After a Facebook user authorizes the app, the user has to be verified manually by a live person which needs to see details of his profile, including his pictures etc.

What would be the correct way to implement this?

Should the app download all necessary data from the user's profile after the user authorizes the app? Seems a lot of wasted effort if there is an easier way.

I have already posted this question to http://webapps.stackexchange.com [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28824/how-do-i-review-a-facebook-app-users-profile-manually).

Answer (score 0):

You can't see a whole lot of details on ones profile without that user having authorized your app. You can however see the ProfilPicture, so if that is most important it would be possible.

And since (I presume) a user starts on your own page/site you could add a check in there so that someone can click an 'accept-button' on your side...

But what I really wonder is, why not just make sure the people you don't want to be authorized with you app don't know where to reach the app??

Think that's way easier to sort out a bunch of people...